# unable to post the data with status code 201

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the below code which works fine but while posting the data I get the below status code 201 while inserting data into my table and while updating the table, I get the mutating table error. Earlier I was able to post the new set of records inserting into my table but now I don't see any records on the URL.

Below is the code:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER get_orders_trig BEFORE
  INSERT OR UPDATE ON orders FOR EACH ROW DECLARE V_RET CLOB;
  BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line('fired-0');
--  if inserting then
--   insert into emp_rows_to_be_processed(p_id) values ( :new.id);
--
--   end if;
    IF inserting THEN
    insert into orders_rows_to_be_processed
    (order_id,source_system) values ( :new.order_id,:new.source_system);

    if  updating 
    then 

   update orders_rows_to_be_processed set 

    source_system = :new.source_system
    where order_id = :new.order_id;

     END IF;
    V_RET := post_json_data_fnc (:new.order_id,:new.source_system);
    END;
    create or replace FUNCTION post_json_data_fnc(

     v_order_id IN NUMBER,
     v_src_system IN VARCHAR2)
      RETURN CLOB
    IS
   req utl_http.req;
   res utl_http.resp;
   url varchar2(200);
   l_clob CLOB;
   l_xml CLOB;
   l_txt CLOB;
    l_http_resp utl_http.resp;

--content varchar2(4000) := '{"name":"u14", "pass": "123","mail": "user@a.om"}';
     BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('Entered the proc');
         URL := 'http call ';

        l_xml   := json_util_pkg.ref_cursor_to_json                 (orders_spec.
          get_orders(v_order_id,v_src_system));
        req := utl_http.begin_request(URL, 'POST',' HTTP/1.1');
        utl_http.set_header(req, 'user-agent', 'mozilla/4.0');
        utl_http.set_header(req, 'content-type', 'application/json');
        utl_http.set_header(req, 'Content-Length', LENGTH(l_xml));
         l_txt := l_xml;
        utl_http.write_text(req, l_txt);
         res := utl_http.get_response(req);
         utl_http.read_text(res,l_txt);

      dbms_output.put_line ('status code: ' || res.status_code);
      dbms_output.put_line ('reason phrase: ' || res.reason_phrase);
       UTL_HTTP.END_RESPONSE(res);
       dbms_output.put_line(l_txt);

            return l_txt;
          EXCEPTION

       WHEN UTL_HTTP.END_OF_BODY THEN
          UTL_HTTP.END_RESPONSE(res);
          END;


                create or replace PACKAGE body orders_spec
       AS
        FUNCTION get_orders(
       v_order_id IN NUMBER,
       v_src_system IN VARCHAR2)
     RETURN sys_refcursor
     AS
      l_returnvalue sys_refcursor;
    BEGIN
      OPEN l_returnvalue FOR SELECT * FROM orders WHERE 
      order_id = v_order_id and source_system = v_src_system; 
       RETURN l_returnvalue;
     dbms_output.put_line('function called');
       END get_orders;
      END orders_spec;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function get_orders is trying to read from the same table the trigger is trying to manipulate (insert or update). The system is just trying to tell you that the table you are trying to reading from is in the middle of being changed so any query will be suspect.

Can't you write the function to just use the data passed to it from the trigger? The trigger already has access to the old data (for updates) and new data (for both inserts and updates). Just pass that to the function.

Comment: @TommCatt..thanks for your update.. I fixed the issue and I am able to update the table but the issue is that I am unable to see the data which is posted on the URL and the status code is shown as 201 and the msg I get after I update/insert is {"_index":"temp","_type":"20","_id":"HLJVdF_oQ6etcS-GlM-Ymg","_score":1.0,"_source":{ }}]}}. Any idea how to fix this? Ideally, I should get status as 200 and the data which ever is updated/inserted should be in the form of JSON

Comment: Getting data from the URL is not something that is handled in a trigger or any code called from a trigger. I don't speak JSON. Sorry.